# Calling nbtstat command using subprocess

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I have a python script which calls the Window's nbtstat command, using subprocess, in order to get the hostname of a computer from its IP address. This is done in cmd using:

`nbtstat -A 172.16.137.2`

Running the below script results in a **WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified**:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['nbtstat', '-A', '172.16.137.2'], std=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I also tried running nbtstat using cmd but got the error message: **'nbtstat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['cmd', '/c', 'nbtstat', '-A', '172.16.137.2'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I don't understand why the nbtstat command works in the command prompt, but not within the script.

Answer (score 0):

I recently suffered from the same issue. I could call 'nbtstat' from command prompt in Windows, but not through subprocess in python. I was able to check with others and found that they successfully returned information where my same code failed, telling me that it was a problem with my local installtion. I first tried the "Repair" option in the installer to no effect.  Only after a complete uninstall and re-install was I able to successfully return information from subprocess calls.